# PI4j Raspberry Pi Infrared receiver

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, pi4j

I have connected a Infrared receiver to Rasberry Pi like this:
[image]

And i have tried the example from URL:
http://pi4j.com/example/listener.html to get information from the GPIO 18 but it outputs nothing into terminal.

Is there any way i can get info from infrared receiver in Java with Pi4j.

I know that the Python script exists but i want to learn if there is possibility to read sensors data from Java.

**UPDATE 1:**

GPIO port 18 is port 1 in Pi4j now i get the output with states LOW HIGH
how can i now decode the signal so i can use it for transmitter.

Comment: Hey Vuk, I know it's a long time since your question appeared here. But how did you manage to achieve your goal?

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to read HIGH and LOW from the sensor, to decode the signal you need to time the lapses between those states, to be able to recognize different signals. Of course, that can be done in Java, for instance using [`System.nanoTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) for precise timing.

There is a good tutorial on how to do this in [Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/ir-sensor/), in particular read from [this section](https://learn.adafruit.com/ir-sensor/ir-remote-signals) on. It is not in Java (it is for Arduino), but the idea can be easily adapted to use Pi4J.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [jlirc](http://jlirc.sourceforge.net/). It uses lirc package on linux.
Install lirc package on your raspberry pi and have it running.